# javascript + html5 audio player cors not play dynamic source

Tags: javascript, html, audio, google-drive-api

Sorry for my English, I'm using a translator.

The question is the following: passing the source of an audio file hosted on Google Drive doesn't work.
But if I pass a source of a local file it works.
Also if the mp3 files are in my domain, it works as well.

Example:

```js
function _playDrive() { //dont work
  let audio = new Audio('http://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=ejemplo'); //is mp3
  audio.controls = true;
  audio.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
  document.body.appendChild(audio);
  audio.play();
}

function _playLocal() { //work
  let audio = new Audio('./mysong.mp3');
  audio.controls = true;
  audio.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
  document.body.appendChild(audio);
  audio.play();
}
```

I would appreciate a solution with no dependencies, thx.

Comment: `driveID` is a unique hash ex. `&id=0Bxp1PlM4alaxOTl6SFM1OTloUUk` not 'papa'

Comment: dear friend function Player(id){    this.init = function(){       this.id = id; ...

this id only for css, not a value of src.

Comment: I simplify the code so that they understand it more easily

Comment: I understood the original code easily. `driveID` should not be `this.id` `driveID` is totally wrong and is the reason why you'll never get it running until you understand how to access a google file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the file id which is a 20+ alphanumeric located after `id=` in the url.

**Base**

**`https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=no_antivirus&id=`**

**File_ID**

**`0B1c82XNzuQ5ZU3RYSmZENERBQjQ`**

#### SOLUTION

> `var player = new Audio(`**Base** `+` **File_ID** `)`

### Demo

```js
var player = new Audio('https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=no_antivirus&id=0B1c82XNzuQ5ZU3RYSmZENERBQjQ');
player.controls = true;
document.body.appendChild(player);
player.play();
```